# MOSS custom MasterPage not displaying on all site pages

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I have created a master page under my top level MOSS site. I have applied it to a sub-site. When I go to some pages such as "Site Settings" the custom master page has not been applied. Do you know why this may be happening? I have set the custom master page as the System and Site page. I am using http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2007/01/26/6153.aspx as the base of my custom master. I have just added div tags and id's to help position elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true - the pages under /_layouts/ folder (for instance, `http://yoursite/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx`) do not use the default.master, rather application.master is used there.

EDIT: You should take a look at another Heater Solomon's article about your problem - http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2006/10/26/5914.aspx